# What's the advantage of some of the constants defined in the Menu class?

Tags: android, constants

I am going through the Notepad tutorial: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/notepad-ex1.html

I notice that the code they provide to add a menu item is

```
  menu.add(0, INSERT_ID, 0, R.string.menu_insert);
```

INSERT_ID is earlier defined as Menu.FIRST . When I go look up that constant in the class, it is an int set to 1. Defined there is also Menu.NONE, which is an int set to 0.

This leads me to wonder about two things:

- **What's the use of defining Menu.FIRST as 1 and Menu.NONE as 0? Why not just provide 1 and 0 during function calls?** Especially since...
- That's essentially what they did in this function call in providing 0. **Why not use Menu.NONE there since they went to the trouble of providing the other constant contained in a local variable?**

From the reference I found that

```
android.view.Menu.add(int groupId, int itemId, int order, int titleRes)
```

where:

> *groupID*: The group identifier that this item should be part of. This
>   can also be used to define groups of items for batch state changes.
>   **Normally use NONE if an item should not be in a group.**
>
> *itemID*: Unique item ID. **Use NONE if you do not need a unique ID.**
>
> *order*: The order for the item. **Use NONE if you do not care about
>   the order.** See getOrder().
>
> *titleRes*: Resource identifier of title string. [not important for
>   this question]

So now I am extra confused that they should use the constant provided in one place yet ignore the instruction to do so in another place, all within the same function call.

Comment: By the way, if this question is generalizable to something useful outside of just the Menu class I would be happy to rephrase it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, using constants has a few advantages over hard coding literals. Having logically named constants can improve the readability of your code. In this particular case, it doesn't help much but

```
menu.add(Menu.NONE, INSERT_ID, Menu.NONE, R.string.menu_insert);
```

is still slightly more readable than

```
menu.add(0, 1, 0, R.string.menu_insert);
```

Defining and using constants also helps with abstracting implementation details. If you use the constant Menu.FIRST, then you don't have to be aware that the implementation identifies the first row as 1 rather than 0. If the implementation is ever changed such that Menu.FIRST is defined as 0 and Menu.NONE is defined as -1, you won't need to go back and change your code in order to accommodate the changes.

In this particular case, it looks like a case of sloppy coding. The code is inconsistent in its use of constants.

Comment: Thanks, I had some suspicion something was amiss.